# Firefox: All my browsers can connect to the internet except Moxilla Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, browser

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and I have been experiencing an issue with **Moxilla Firefox** connecting to the internet for a few days now. The issue started after a recent update to my Firefox browser application.

All my other browsers **(Google Chrome, Opera)** and working very fine, but I can't seem to tell why **Moxilla Firefox** is not connecting to the internet.

I have tried to reset my network, cleared my history, cleared my cache, closed all my active tabs and even restarted my Ubuntu machine several times, but all to no avail.

I need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to the issue of not connecting to the internet using **Moxilla Firefox** on an Ubuntu Machine (This may work on for Operating Systems as well).

1. Open FireFox and enter `about:config` in the Search/URL box.
2. Click the **I accept the risk** when the security warning page shows up.
3. Type and enter `network.dns.disableIPv6` in the Search box.
4. Click on it **network.dns.disableIPv6** to change it's value from `false` to `true`.

[image: Screenshot of expected action]

5. Restart your **Moxilla Firefox** browser, and try connecting to the internet again.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**